# Differentiating between enum and field

Tags: java, enums

I am making a card game. I made a card class that can store a card's suit and value. I am using an enum to keep track of the suit and value of the card. When I try to use the enum I have problems differentiating between the Enum "Suit" and the Field "Suit". How should I name the Emum "Suit" and the Field "Suit" so that they do not have the same name?

```
public class Card 
    {

        public enum Suit
        {
            SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS;
        }

        public enum Value
        {
              ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
              SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING;
        }

        Suit Suit;
        Value Value;

        public Card(Suit suit, Value value)
        {
            Suit = suit
            Value = value
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow naming conventions** [(1)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) [(2)](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

- Class/Enum names should be CamelCase, starting with an uppercase letter.
- Field/method names should be camelCase, starting with a lowecase letter.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
Suit Suit;
Value Value;
```

use:

```
Suit suit;
Value value;
```

Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can name the identifier anything, as per convention, but the type that exist in the scope (package/super etc..) 
here `Suit` & `Value` also are type. for example you can give `suit` & `value` as name (notice the lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

Use Suit for the Enum, and suit for the field.

Comment: `suite`? Why not just `suit`?